# How can we allocate a buffer that we are sure won't be paged?

Tags: c, linux

Maybe this one thing is related to buffer allocation in kernel. 
Suppose we want to write a music player, if paging happens, this may lead to choppy low quality music playing.
 Video Player, we want to write a real time software, or anything. 
We want to assign one of the CPUs to a process, or we make a process very high priority, and then we want to make sure our buffer won't be paged to HDD. How is it done in C and Linux?

Comment: I don't think you can do this from usermode.

Comment: Check out `mlockall` system call, maybe related to what you want.

Comment: @sjr: You should post that as an answer. `mlock` is the way to lock a single buffer, but if you also want to make sure your code doesn't get paged out, which would hurt latency just as bad as data getting paged out, you need `mlockall`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By calling:

```
int mlock(const void *addr, size_t len);//included in header #include <sys/mman.h>
```

with the start address of the area and its length, the system will guarantee that the memory specified will reside in RAM until you call

```
int munlock(const void *addr, size_t len);
```

You can also call the function `mlockall(MCL_FUTURE);` which will make all your following memory allocations be RAM residents but this poses the risk of allocating more than what's physically available and the result is implementation dependent.

**EDIT:**
For more details, check the following links:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/mlock.html
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/mlockall.html

**EDIT2: Zan Lynx's comment** 
Also note that using this to lock more than 64KB (on most Linux systems) will require root privileges. Best way in my opinion is to have a wrapper that launches as root, sets up relaxed real-time and memory lock requirements, switches user IDs and then runs the actual program.

**P.S** Normally when RT requirments arise, not only you lock your program in RAM but you also set the scheduler into real-time mode, for that you can check `sched_setscheduler(..)`

Comment: Also note that using this to lock more than 64KB (on most Linux systems) will require root privileges. Best way in my opinion is to have a wrapper that launches as root, sets up relaxed real-time and memory lock requirements, switches user IDs and then runs the actual program.

Comment: Thanks, I added your comment to the answer.

Comment: You might also add that the way to check the limit on locked memory is to execute `ulimit -l` in the shell. Also this is the way that higher or lower limits might be set (but if not `root`, one cannot set the limit higher than the hard limit, obtainable by `ulimit -lH`). The default on older Ubuntu distributions is 32 KiB.